# How to overwrite values during a select query in sql?

Tags: sql, select

Suppose I have a table foo with schema (name, age). So the table looks like:

```
NAME | AGE
John | 20
Jane | 50
Jason | 30
```

Now suppose I wanted to select from this table, but I wanted to change all their ages to 20 via the select query. That is, I don't want to update the original table foo, but I want to select, something like:

```
SELECT name, 20 as age from foo
```

In other words, I want to manipulate the data on the select. Of course, my real-life example is much more complicated than this but knowing the answer to this will do. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try it? It will work just fine as you have it. Numbers needn't be quoted, but for string values you would need to single quote as in `SELECT name, 'Jones' AS lastname FROM foo`

Comment: http://www.sqlcourse.com/select.html The query doesn't work on this website, so I assumed...

Comment: If you want to test SQL online, I recommend http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I see. Thanks Michael for the super quick response!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically just do what you put in your question:

```
SELECT name, newValue as age
from yourTable
```

This will give you the `name` from your table and then the value you specify for the other column.

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c1ea/1)